# what parameters i need to pass for paymentIntentClientSecret in stripe payment method?

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

i m creating stripe payment method but i dont know what paymentIntentClientSecret takes so please help me there is my code

```
 await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          applePay: true,
          googlePay: true,
          style: ThemeMode.dark,
          testEnv: true,
          merchantCountryCode: 'US',
          merchantDisplayName: 'Flutter Stripe Store Demo',
          customerId: "4242424242424242",
          paymentIntentClientSecret:"",
          customerEphemeralKeySecret:"sk_test_51JfOcKL28pDgfM8ZNcOgXcOau98OqZMoauV9Qq4fG06rsrHjL2olm4oIkd4DQCCuOh3079xJIo0t1KGNiv5c382L00ZNJHlCaU",

        ));
```

Comment: It's only a test mode key but you probably shouldn't paste your API key publicly like this. https://stripe.com/docs/keys#safe-keys

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/stripe_platform_interface/latest/stripe_platform_interface/SetupPaymentSheetParameters/paymentIntentClientSecret.html), it seems like paymentIntentClientSecret takes a string.

```
paymentIntentClientSecret property Null safety
String? paymentIntentClientSecret

inherited

Secret used for client-side retrieval using a publishable key.
If this value is null make sure to add a setupIntentClientSecret
```

Again based on the [doc](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_sdk/versions/1.1.0/example), it comes from running

```
final paymentIntentClientSecret =
      await _createPaymentIntent(Stripe.getReturnUrl());

/// Create payment intent and return the client secret.
/// The `return_url` must be set on the PaymentIntent.
/// https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/android#create-payment-intent
Future<String> _createPaymentIntent(String returnUrl) {
  return Future.value("client_secret");
}
```

Comment: stripe_sdk 1.1.0  bro this is depricated you cant use this library anymore

Comment: i m talking about flutter stripe library